# Does metainit have a directive to generate a log file?

Tags: init-script, init.d

Does [metainit](https://wiki.debian.org/MetaInit) have a directive to generate a log file by redirecting process's standard output stream to it?

The naive way of:

```
Exec: /srv/wordy/wordy >/var/log/wordy.log
```

does not seem to work since metainit parses redirects as `arguments` and the result looks like this:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --oknodo --background --quiet --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
                $DAEMON_ARGS || return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I found was to modify the generated `/etc/init.d` script after running `update-metainit`. Unfortunately this is an extra step now but at least it works. Info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251933/how-can-i-log-the-stdout-of-a-process-started-by-start-stop-daemon):

Replace the -exec part of the start-stop-daemon call line 57:

```
   "--exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS || return 1"
```

with:

```
   "--startas /bin/bash -- -c "exec $DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS  >> /var/log/app.log 2>&1" || return 1"
```